# force:chatter publisher not showing POST tab (cannot create posts on record)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, chatter, record, publisher

As per documentation of forceChatter:publisher, forceChatter:publisher allows users create posts on records or groups and upload attachments from their desktops in Lightning.

When the following line is exectued i see the following output

```
 <aura:if isTrue="{!v.recordId}">
                <forceChatter:publisher context="RECORD" recordId="{!v.recordId}"/>
                <forceChatter:feed type="record" subjectId="{!v.recordId}"/>
 </aura:if>
```

The output that i get is:
[image]

When i change the context of forceChatter:publisher to GLOBAL, I see Post, Poll, Question tabs but when i update the context to RECORD I do not see the post tab
Am i missing something? Any help on how  i can create posts with context = RECORD in forceChatter:publisher.

NOTE: In the image, I posted posts on that record using process builder.

Comment: On which object are you trying to use `forceChatter:publisher` ? Are you adding your lightning component on the lightning record page ?

Comment: @Shamina I am adding forceChatter:publisher in my custom lightning component that has lightning:urlAddressable interface (where we pass the recordId as well)

Comment: is the recordId for a custom or standard object? you probably have already done this, but make sure Feed tracking is enabled for this object

Comment: @Shamina The recordId is of custom object and yes feed tracking is already enabled for the object. When I change the status of field , I can see the update in chatter feed saying fied value change to something. 
However, I cannot get the post tab using forceChatter:publisher.

Comment: I tried for a custom object and `forceChatter:publisher` shows the Post,Poll and Questions tabs. In your screenshot, the "Chatter" title and icon on the left looks strange, these are displayed for me. There could be something conflicting in your code, could you edit your question and post more of your lightning component code so that we have more info ?

Comment: @Shamina, Did you put context="RECORD" in your forceChatter:publisher component? Is it a global context or what? Can you share your code plz.

Comment: Yes context="RECORD". Note that there was a typo in my previous comment, I meant: "Chatter" title and icon are NOT displayed for me". Not enough space to share the code in comment here, check my answer and screenshot (I can delete the answer afterwards if needed). Also, as suggested, you could share some more of your code so that we can have a better idea what may be going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

@lambad as requested in comment, here is the result of a test to show that the issue cannot be reproduced.

Added simple lightning component (API v.47) into a lightning page called "Custom Chatter Publisher".

Note that `forceChatter:publisher` is of context="RECORD"

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" >
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" default="a014J000007CAtXQAW" /> 
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.recordId}" >
        <forceChatter:publisher context="RECORD" recordId="{!v.recordId}"/> <br/>
        <forceChatter:feed type="Record" subjectId="{!v.recordId}"/>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

Post, Poll, Question tabs are correctly shown in the lightning page below:

[image]

Comment: I got the reason. It is salesforce issue and i have posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why forceChatter:publisher did not show tab was because i was using it in custom component.
This is an issue in salesforce itself. Here Is the link

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008gACQAY

Comment: is this known issue really applicable? because it concerns `context="Global"` and as per my understanding you needed `context=RECORD`.  You could also log a case with Salesforce support for your issue

Comment: @Shamina, I made a component and used in flexipage of standard object (Account) and everything worked fine.
When i added the component in custom object flexipage, i could not  see publisher section and only chatter:feed section was shown.

Comment: @Shamina,
Even this issue links to same thing
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000Xky6QAC

Comment: @Shamina, Can you test your fix in standard and custom object?

Comment: for me it works for both standard and custom object, I am doing this test in a developer org in winter 20 release (api 47). Are you running your component in a prelease org or sandbox preview under spring 20 release (api 48) ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on an Opportunity Sobject.
When I added *Post* Action to the Page Layout of the Sobject, publisher showed up.

...

```
<aura:if isTrue="{! v.rendered }">
<div class="slds-section__content" id="chatter">
          <forceChatter:publisher recordId="{!v.recordId}" context="RECORD"/>
          <forceChatter:feed type="Record" subjectId="{!v.recordId}" aura:id="text"/>
</aura:if>
```

...

[image]